# Anyway to ignore a certain coordinate axis in the PlayerMoveEvent using getFrom and getTo

Tags: java, minecraft

So im making an anti speed hacking plugin in java using PlayerMoveEvent to calculate the distance a player moves compared to the speed limit, is there a way to ignore the y axis so the player doesn't get kicked while falling? I've done a bunch of research on the  spigot event and there isn't that much information, any help is appreciated!

```
    public void getLimit(PlayerMoveEvent e) {
        Player player = e.getPlayer();
        if(e.getFrom().distance(e.getTo()) > 0.8) {
            player.kickPlayer("Too fast");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's two ways you can do this. The first way is to do the math yourself instead of using `distance`:

```
    public void getLimit(PlayerMoveEvent e) {
        Player player = e.getPlayer();
        Location from = e.getFrom();
        Location to = e.getTo();
        double dx = to.getX() - from.getX();
        double dz = to.getZ() - from.getZ();
        if(dx * dx + dz * dz > 0.64) {
            player.kickPlayer("Too fast");
        }
    }
```

The second way is to make a vector with a zero y-axis distance, and then measure it:

```
    public void getLimit(PlayerMoveEvent e) {
        Player player = e.getPlayer();
        Location from = e.getFrom();
        Location to = e.getTo().clone();
        to.setY(from.getY());
        if(from.distance(to) > 0.8) {
            player.kickPlayer("Too fast");
        }
    }
```